# Why is the jQuery on("click", "button", ...) running before the button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm just learning jquery, and I'm running into behavior I don't understand. I have:

html:

```
<div id="tour" data-location="london">
    <button>Get Photos</button>
    <ul class="photos"></ul>
</div>
```

and
jquery:

```
var tour = {
    init: function () {
        $("#tour").on("click", "button", alert("clicked"));
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("hello");
    tour.init();
});
```

The "hello" alert is appearing after the dom is loaded, as I would expect. However the "clicked" alert is firing as well, and does not subsequently fire when the button is pressed.

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/295sgf5c/2/

Comment: You need to wrap the alert in an anonymous handler. That is how event handling works. Currently `init()` call fires the alert. http://jsfiddle.net/295sgf5c/3/

Comment: `alert("clicked")` is passed as a method parameter - it is therefore evaluated.

Answer (score 7):

If you want it to be executed when clicking on the button, you would need to wrap it in a function:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/secvbjd0/)

```
var tour = {
    init: function () {
        $("#tour").on("click", "button", function () {
            alert("clicked")
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/295sgf5c/1/).

Your callback needs to be a function, like this:

```
var tour = {
    init: function () {
        $("#tour").on("click", "button", function(e){alert("clicked")});
    }
};
```